# Generating LuaCov Report file?

Tags: eclipse, testing, lua, code-coverage

I'm using luacov for coverage testing and I can't seem to figure out how to generate the report file. I'm using the Lua Eclipse IDE and have a test script. I've managed to generate the stats file.

The directions say:

```
 To generate a report, just run the  luacov  command-line script.
```

But I'm not sure what this means. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Run `luacov` from a terminal, there is no IDE plugin.

Comment: You can add `runreport = true;` option in `.luacov` file.

Comment: @moteus Thank you for the solution. I found the option in the defaults.lua file and it worked.